# Google Spreadsheet: How to merge two colums downwards into one?

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, google-sheets, google-apps

I have two colums with seperate names on one sheet (C3:C35) and (E3:E35). Now on another sheet I would like to merge them by adding the names all together in one colum (A:A). The names of both colums should be listed downwards, one below the other.

Is it possible to merge the two colums into one?

```
C         E
---------------
Tom       Paul
Leon      Edgar
```

should be merged to:

```
A
--
Tom
Leon
Paul
Edgar
```

I tried on Sheet3 `=ArrayFormula(Sheet!C3:C35+Sheet!E3:E35)` which I found here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275

This try was better `={C3:C35; E3:C35}` but merges also all the empty fields at the end of the columns C and E.

Any help or direction will be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you in advance! Smite

Comment: You say C and E are on the same sheet, but your formula has them on different sheets. And is the destination column A on the same sheet as well?

Comment: Ok, solved: `={filter(Liste!C3:C35; LEN(Liste!C3:C35)); Filter(Liste!E3:E35; LEN(Liste!E3:E35))}` finally did the trick.

Comment: @Nathan: Your'e right. I tweaked the line manually for the question here. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

```
=FILTER({C3:C35; E3:E35},{C3:C35; E3:E35}<>"")
```

## Explanation

The above formula is shorter than the one included in a comment of the question by the OP

```
={filter(Liste!C3:C35; LEN(Liste!C3:C35)); Filter(Liste!E3:E35; LEN(Liste!E3:E35))}
```

## Reference

[Using arrays in Google Sheets - Sheets Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)